# Angular - Re-arrange array items based on dragNDrop and dropdown

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular8

I have 5 images to display and what i want is to maintain the order of these images as per their index.
There are 2 ways by which content can be changed:

1. By Drag and drop: works fine but drop down value is not getting changed.
2. By selecting drop down value -
   In this drop down value would be in the order 1,2,3,4 and 5.

If I want to change the order of the first image(1) and select 3 then image at 3rd place should be swapped
 with image at 1st place and now order is still same but the content is swapped.

I have added comments in code for further understanding. could anyone help me out with this?

sharing a hosted demo on stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swapwithdargdrop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked your StackBlitz and implemented element swapping triggered by drop-down value change.

Here's the resulting `select` element.

```
<select [value]="obj.dropDownIndex" (change)="swap(obj.dropDownIndex - 1, $event.target.value - 1)">
    <option *ngFor="let options of dynamicDropDownArray;" [value]='options.id'>
        {{options.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

and the `swap` method in the component class.

```
swap(index1: number, index2: number): void {
    const element1 = this.photosArray[index1];
    const element2 = this.photosArray[index2];
    const element1DropdownIndex = element1.dropDownIndex;
    element1.dropDownIndex = element2.dropDownIndex;
    element2.dropDownIndex = element1DropdownIndex;

    this.photosArray[index1] = element2;
    this.photosArray[index2] = element1;
}
```

> Note that when swapping the elements in the array, their `dropDownIndex` must also be exchanged.

**UPDATE**

Instead of using `dropDownIndex`, we can simplify the code and query the element index from `photosArray`. This results in the following code snippets.

HTML template:

```
<select [value]="photosArray.indexOf(obj) + 1" (change)="swap(photosArray.indexOf(obj), $event.target.value - 1)">
    <option *ngFor="let options of dynamicDropDownArray;" [value]='options.id'>
        {{options.value}}
    </option>
</select>
```

component class:

```
swap(index1: number, index2: number): void {
    const element1 = this.photosArray[index1];
    const element2 = this.photosArray[index2];
    this.photosArray[index1] = element2;
    this.photosArray[index2] = element1;
}
```

Please have a look at my amended [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/swapwithdargdrop-ivjbkm?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: thank you for your effort on this. i can see my second scenario is working as expected but in 1st scenario on drag and drop, dropdown values are not getting updated. any idea about it ?

Comment: I applied debugger in your swap function and was checking on the 'app' url of stackblitz, it is getting crashed frequently. could you please check?

Comment: I made a fix in the `drop` method and not it works when all images are displayed in the the same row (if screen is wide enough). Otherwise `event.previousIndex` and  `event.currentIndex` have wrong values. Therefore, you better post a new question to get an answer for this new issue.